# Trying to remove extra space from menu created in website

Tags: html, css, image, list, css-float

In my code supplied below, I am seeing that either something with my CSS or HTML is wrong because I had created a side menu using the example from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp. I added this example to my web page and for some reason there is some extra space on the left that is showing and it is not clickable as a link (which it should be). I am also using Aptana Studio 3 for this project and for some reason it is showing in the CSS file an error for `100vh`, but I don't think that is the problem.

```css
html {
  background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.divSize {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
#navmenu {
  float: left;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div align="right" class="divSize">
      <img src="images/myimage.png" alt="My Image" style="width: 145px; height: 86px">
      <div id="navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff1">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff2">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff3">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff4">Stuff</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: also just noticed the lange in the opening html tag. Corrected it to lang for the opening html tag.

Comment: `padding 0;` should be `padding: 0;`. Typo-related questions are off-topic. Just use the browser’s developer tools as your debugger. View the box model, view the applied CSS rules. Then you should notice that the `padding` rule is missing. Carefully look at the `padding` rule and you’ll notice the wrong syntax.

Comment: Just changed the code. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in `padding` applied to the `ul`- fixed it and there you go!

```css
html {
  background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.divSize {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
#navmenu {
  float: left;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <div align="right" class="divSize">
      <img src="images/myimage.png" alt="My Image" style="width: 145px; height: 86px">
      <div id="navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff1">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff2">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff3">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff4">Stuff</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice web designers tend to use is to use include the "*" or universal selector in the first line of CSS to get rid of some of the default margin and padding.

```
//At the top of your CSS put
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

It will adjust the space nicely.
For future reference, I recommend using bootstrap. It will make you happy.

Comment: Thanks for the input! It has proved to help me in many web project I have worked on so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
html {
  background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.divSize {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

#navmenu {
  float: left;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>

    <div align="right" class="divSize">
      <img src="images/myimage.png" alt="My Image" style="width: 145px; height: 86px">
      <div id="navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff1">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff2">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff3">Stuff</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#stuff4">Stuff</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```